# How do I remove the header & footer from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, screen-reader

How do I remove the header & footer from a PDF? I was successful in opening the PDF in PDF Viewer Plus, selecting crop, all pages, .25" top and bottom. This removes the viewing of the text, however the text is still embedded in the document. When I try to use a screen reader, it still reads the headers and footers even though they are not visible. How do I remove them completely? I tried to print to PDF but it created an 80 MB image based PDF and lost all text information. I need to keep the text. I tried PDF Scissors also and it too just hid the text, which was still in the file.

Comment: Are we talking about the Nuance PDF Viewer Plus ?

Comment: Can you add a full screenshot of one of the pages?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, Nuance makes it.

Comment: Use Adobe Acrobat and set the crop box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open PDF in PDF Viewer Plus > Save as XPS > Open XPS in 7-Zip > Extract to folder > Open document\Pages\1.fpage in Notepad++ (is XML) > File/Global search & replace the header and footer > Create .zip file with 7-Zip > Rename to .xps > Open in PDF Reader (XPS not an option but it will open it anyways with wrong title bar) > File > Save As > Document_Fixed.pdf > Open in Foxit Reader > Engage screen reader > Voilá!

Update: Saving as XPS will position each individual word on the page, and the resulting screen reader rendition is a jumble of individual words in quick succession with all cadence and sentence structure lost! It is impossible to listen to.

Instead, in Foxit > File > Save As > TXT > Open in Notepad++ > Search & Replace '---- Page 1----' using regular expression and replacing with blank > Search & Replace header/footer > Save > Open in Open Office Writer > Fiddle with page margins and font size to approximate original PDF > Saves as document_fixed.PDF > Open in FoxIt > Engage screen reader > Voilá!

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess here since it was not specified, that you are using the Nuance PDF Viewer Plus.

Nuance PDF Viewer Plus has limited editing capability.

You best choice is to export the pdf to word, modify it there and save as pdf.

Comment: My version (12 SE I believe) doesn't support exporting the PDF to MS Word. It only supports saving as XPS. But once I have it as XPS, I see no way to convert it back into PDF (text).

Comment: Consider this https://nuancepdf.com/PDFReader/Download.aspx

Comment: Thanks! They never mailed me the converted Word doc after I uploaded, but I did find PDF Reader could open XPS and save as PDF. My solution: Open PDF in PDF Viewer Plus, Save as XPS, Open XPS in 7-Zip, Extract to folder, Open document\Pages\1.fpage in Notepad++ (is XML), File search & replace the header and footer, Create .zip file with 7-Zip, Rename to .xps, open in PDF Reader (XPS not an option but it will open it anyways with wrong title bar), File, Save As, Document_Fixed.pdf, Open in Foxit Reader, Engage screen reader, Voilá!

Comment: Please not Word. Acrobat is the tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 step:

1. Convert pdf file to word. You can open Microsoft Office Words, then open pdf file by MS Words to convert file to word.
2. Edit footer then save file as pdf again.